# How to add one day to a date in Fitnesse

Tags: date, fitnesse

I'm capturing a date from the response message and now I want to create a new request with the date +1 in the payload of the new request.  What's the code for that in Fitnesse?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please take some time and complete [Welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0):

That requires some (Java) code as far as I'm aware. Depending on which fixtures you are using you can either use an existing fixture method for that, or you'll have to write your own custom function/method.